# jquery select specific dd

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making some FAQ accordion. 
I need to **select all but first** `dd` and hide em all.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z1v463x/)
Basically, I want the answer 1 to be shown when the page loads, and I don't want to insert any id or class into html. What is the easiest way to accomplish this

```js
$('dd').hide();
$('dl').on('mouseenter', 'dt', function() {
  $(this).next().slideDown(200);
  $(this).next().siblings('dd').slideUp(200);
});
```

```css
dt {
  background-color: #d464d4;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
dd {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt>FAQ1</dt>
  <dd>Answer 1</dd>
  <dt>FAQ2</dt>
  <dd>Answer 2</dd><dt>FAQ3</dt>
  <dd>Answer 3</dd><dt>FAQ4</dt>
  <dd>Answer 4</dd><dt>FAQ5</dt>
  <dd>Answer 5</dd>
  <dt>FAQ6</dt>
  <dd>Answer 6</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('dd:nth-child(n+4)').hide();`

This mean you are selecting every `dd` which is the `n+4` child of his parent.
 *`n` is starting at 0, and increments.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('dd:gt(0)').hide();
```

Also :gt(n) filter starts the selection after the "n" element. In this case from the 2nd `<dd>`. (Since :gt() is not css, but jquery count starts from "0")